# Does $\gcd(x^{p^2+p+1}-1, (x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1)\neq 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for all primes $p$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

It seems that for every prime $p$, $x^{p^2+p+1}-1$ and $(x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1$ are not coprime in $\mathbb{F}_p$. In other words, it seems that there is always a $(p-1)$-th power $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}^\times$ such that $x+1$ is also a $(p-1)$-th power in $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}^\times$.

Using PARI, one can calculate the degree of $\gcd(x^{p^2+p+1}-1, (x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ as follows:
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        p & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 23 & 29 & 31 & 37 & 41 & 43 & 47 & 53 & 59 & 61 & 67 & 71 & 73 & 79 & 83 & 89 & 97 \\ \hline
        d & 6 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 12 & 18 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 36 & 36 & 36 & 36 & 36 & 60 & 48 & 66 & 54 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 90 & 96 & 108 \\ \hline
    \end{array}
We can see that the degree listed here are very close to $p$. Also, $p=7$ is the only case where  $\gcd(x^{p^2+p+1}-1, (x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1)$ has a linear factor. If we remove that factor, then every degree here is divisible by $6$.

If we replace $p^2+p+1$ by $p^4+p^3+p^2+p+1$, we observe a similar pattern: the degree for $p=2,3,5,7,11,13,17$ is respectively $30,60,200,460,1642,2560,5590$. This seems to have a cubic growth with $p$, and after removing the linear factors for $p=11$, every degree seems to be divisible by $10$.

We have
$$
(x+1)^{p^2+p+1} = x^{p^2+p+1} + x^{p^2+p} + x^{p^2+1} + x^{p^2} + x^{p+1} + x^p + x + 1,
$$
but this does not seem to simplify $\gcd(x^{p^2+p+1}-1, (x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1)$, so I think there must be a deeper reason for $\gcd(x^{p^2+p+1}-1, (x+1)^{p^2+p+1}-1)\neq 1$. Any idea appreciated.

I would like also to add that, since $3|(p^2+p+1)$ for $p\equiv 1\pmod 6$, I have also tested $\gcd(x^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{3}}-1, (x+1)^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{3}}-1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, which seems to be nonconstant other than $p=7,13,37,43,79$.

Comment: Do you mean in $\mathbb F_p[x]?$

Comment: The reason why it is divisible by 6 (or 10 for $\mathbb{F}_{p^5}$) is that you get $n$ from the irreducible polynomial factors splitting in extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p$ (since you should not be getting them in $\mathbb{F}_p$) and you also have the symmetry $x\leftrightarrow -1/x$ that pairs the factors.  The extra linear factor in $p=7$ comes from an accidental $(1+1)^3=1$.

Comment: If we homogenize, we are looking at the $\Bbb{F}_{p^3}$ rational points of $$X^{p-1}+Y^{p-1}=Z^{p-1}.$$ Dehomogenize by setting $Y=1$. May be studying suitable Jacobi sums gives the main claim?

Comment: That curve has too high a genus for the general Weil bound to kick in. We could try and use a normal basis of $\Bbb{F}_{p^3}/\Bbb{F}_p$ turning the main question to an intersection of two cubic surfaces in $\Bbb{F}_p^3$, but that is too vague.

Comment: Approaching it from another (likely useless) angle. The gcd is the product of irreducible cubics in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ of the form $r(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx-1$ such that $r(-1)=-1$. It follows that we can count the number of such polynomials, if we find the tally. But I don't see a way of using this to prove the existence :-)

Comment: For the $\mathbb{F}_{p^5}$ case indeed we can use Fourier transform methods such as Theorem 0.2 (proved as Theorem 7.1) [here](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/reu02/fourier.pdf).  The bound there is too weak for $p^3$ case though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes; edited.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for your comment and the link provided! The result is very powerful as it solves the case $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ for all primes $r\ge 5$, so $r=3$ is the only case left.

Comment: For $r=3$ characters alone doesn't work.  You need to use more sophisticated version known as [Kloosterman sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kloosterman_sum).  There must be a simpler way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jyrki Lahtonen notes in the comments, the gcd is the product of all monic irreducible cubic polynomials $f(x)$ in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ such that $f(0) = f(-1) = -1$. So we're asking for the existence of an irreducible cubic of the form $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 +(a-1)x - 1$.

Since this is a cubic polynomial, it is irreducible if and only if it has a root in $\Bbb{F}_p$. Note also that neither $0$ nor $-1$ is a root of $f(x)$ since $f(0) = f(-1) = -1$.

If $x$ is a root, we have $x^3-x-1 + a(x^2 + x) = 0$, so

$$a = \frac{x^3 -x - 1}{-x^2 - x}.$$

But then since $x \ne 0$ and $x \ne -1$, there are at most $p-2$ values of $a$ that satisfy the above equation for some $x \in \Bbb{F}_p$. So for at least $2$ values of $a$, $f(x)$ does not not have a root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ and is therefore irreducible.

So the degree of the gcd is at least $6$.

Comment: Well done!!${}$